# How to use a service or provider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular and am working on some dummy application to make myself comfortable with angular. I have designed a small contact app using angular and firebase. Everything seems to working fine, but I put all the logic inside a controller; I want to separate it out to a service/provider.

Here is the structure of my current application:

```js
angular.module('myContacts.contact', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/contacts', {
    templateUrl: 'contacts/contacts.html',
    controller: 'contactsCtrl'
  });
}])

.controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray',function($scope,$firebaseArray) {


 var ref = new Firebase('https://micontactapp.firebaseio.com/contacts');
 $scope.contacts = $firebaseArray(ref);

 $scope.addFormShow = false;
 $scope.msg = "";

 $scope.showAddForm = function(){
  $scope.addFormShow = true;
 }
 $scope.hide = function(){
  $scope.addFormShow = false;
 }

 $scope.closeDetailsForm = function(){
  $scope.showDetailsForm = false; 
 

 $scope.showContactDetails = function(contact){

  // To show the details on po
 }

 $scope.addFormSubmit = function() {
  console.log("form submitted.");
  var name = $scope.name ? $scope.name : null;
  var email = $scope.email ? $scope.email : null;
  var company = $scope.company ? $scope.company : null;

  var work_phone = $scope.work_phone ? $scope.work_phone : null;
  var mobile_phone = $scope.mobile_phone ? $scope.mobile_phone : null;
  var home_phone = $scope.home_phone ? $scope.home_phone : null;

  var street_address = $scope.street_address ? $scope.street_address : null;
  var city = $scope.city ? $scope.city : null;
  var state = $scope.state ? $scope.state : null;
  var zipcode = $scope.zip ? $scope.zip : null;
 

  $scope.contacts.$add({
   name: name,
   email: email,
   company: company,
   phones: [
    {
     mobile: mobile_phone,
     home: home_phone,
     work: work_phone
    }
   ],
   addresses: [{
    street_address: street_address,
    city: city,
    state: state,
    zipcode: zipcode 
   }]
  }).then(function(ref){
   var id = ref.key();
   console.log("Added Contact with id"+id);

   $scope.clearFields();
   $scope.addFormShow = false;
   $scope.msg = "Contact Added.";
  });
 }
 

 $scope.removeContact = function(contact){
  $scope.contacts.$remove(contact);
  $scope.msg = "Contact removed.";
 };

 $scope.showEditForm = function(contact){

  console.log(contact.$id);
  $scope.id = contact.$id;
  $scope.name = contact.name;
  $scope.email = contact.email;
  $scope.company = contact.company;

  $scope.work_phone = contact.phones[0].work;
  $scope.mobile_phone = contact.phones[0].mobile;
  $scope.home_phone = contact.phones[0].home;

  $scope.street_address = contact.addresses[0].street_address;
  $scope.city = contact.addresses[0].city;
  $scope.state = contact.addresses[0].state;
  $scope.zipcode = contact.addresses[0].zipcode;
  
  $scope.editFormShow = true;
 }

 $scope.editFormSubmit = function(contact){
  var id = $scope.id;
  console.log(id);
  var record = $scope.contacts.$getRecord(id);

  record.name = $scope.name;
  record.company = $scope.company;
  record.email = $scope.email;

  record.phones[0].home = $scope.home_phone;
  record.phones[0].work = $scope.work_phone;
  record.phones[0].mobile = $scope.mobile_phone;

  record.addresses[0].street_address = $scope.street_address;
  record.addresses[0].city = $scope.city;
  record.addresses[0].state = $scope.state;
  record.addresses[0].zip = $scope.zipcode;

  $scope.contacts.$save(record).then(function(ref){
   $scope.msg = "Record updated.";
  });

  $scope.clearFields();
  $scope.editFormShow = false;

 }

}]);
```

Basically I am creating a reference of firebase(`var ref = new Firebase('https://micontactapp.firebaseio.com/contacts');`) and using that all CRUD operations are done.

If I create a new service layer, I am not sure where I should create this reference controller or service? Should I use a factory or provider?

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory to define a service and to reuse the code. Here is an example how you can use it.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);   
app.factory('utility',function() {
    return {
         method : function($scope) {
            //put your reusable code
         }
    }
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('contactsCtrl', ['$scope','$firebaseArray','utility',function($scope,$firebaseArray,utility) {
    utility.method($scope);
}]);
```

Comment: Is it good use $scope inside a service/factory ? Is it recommended ?

Comment: yes you have to inject $scope inside the factory because the method/function defined inside a factory contains reusable code which is to be used across multiple controllers and data binding is necessary using $scope inside the controllers.

Comment: Did you find the information useful. You can cross check with the doc or go through examples to cross verify the above mentioned statement. I hope i am able to help you @user3714162

Answer (score 0):

See there are three things which you can actually do

- Define your logic inside app.run
- Define your logic inside app.service or app.factory

While using your code try to use $rootScope instead of $scope as the variables or function needs to be global throughout the module

Do look as when you use the above functions